Azure API Management Developer Portal: How to display operations of a specific tag and API?
How can I display a list of operations of a specific tag and API to a user on a web page using the visual editor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-overview)?
E.g. I have a web page in my Azure API Developer Portal describing a customer service. On this page I want to display all operations that have the "customer" tag.
I have tried it using the widget "List of operations". However, there seems no be no option unfortunately:


Alternatively, you can use Rest Api GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiId}/operationsByTags?api-version=2022-08-01 to get the list of operations by specific tag

You can also filter it in this way

Thanks @IkhtesamAfrin. I want to display operations on a web page of the Azure API Developer Portal and I am using the visual editor to design the portal
